# PHP ternary operator expecting colon and semicolon

Tags: php

This ternary operator within an element is giving an error:

```
<div class="col-sm<?php $columnCasecheck === true ? echo '-3' : echo '-4' ?>">
```

PhpStorm is expecting a colon after `true ?` and a semicolon after `'-3'`. Why is that? It seems like a valid ternary operator to me. See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: "seems like a valid ternary operator to me" But it is not valid.

Comment: `echo` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: In other words, the ternary operator is not a short-cut syntax for the `if` flow control structure, it's something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $columnCasecheck === true ? '-3' : '-4'; ?>
```

Inside the ternary you should put `value` or `expression`, instead of commands.
So the `echo` should be outside the `ternary expression`.

Also, if you don't need `strict comparison`, you can just write:

```
<?php echo $columnCasecheck ? '-3' : '-4'; ?>
```

So your whole line will be:

```
<div class="col-sm<?php echo $columnCasecheck ? '-3' : '-4'; ?>">
```

Comment: If OP wants strict comparison, `===` isn't "unnecessary."

Comment: @miken32  Yeah, you're right, I'll rephrase it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take your echo out of an expression as follows -
`<?php echo $columnCasecheck === true ? '-3' : '-4'; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<?php $columnCasecheck = $columnCasecheck === true ? '-3' : '-4'; ?>

<div class="col-sm<?=$columnCasecheck?>>value</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to output the result, just put the *echo* in front of the expression:

```
echo $columnCasecheck === true ? '-3' : '-4';
```